# Stripe Payment Error : While sending stripe token from iOS to php

Tags: php, ios

Actually we are try send send token which is generated by stripe ios sdk but when we send that generated token to server using php  it show me below error

"**Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\ApiConnection' with message 'Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges).
If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com**."

Please help us to solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

From source code:

```
when RestClient::RequestTimeout
      message = "Could not connect to Stripe (#{api_base_url}). #{connection_message}"
```

Check if your internet issue or ping the url https://api.stripe.com/

Comment: Using following command "ping https://api.stripe.com/" i ma getting following respoce. 
PING https://api.stripe.com/ (198.105.244.11): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq . what does it means......??

Comment: it means you can't connect to stripe server. Where are you from, i think maybe it was blocked in your city? Or just try ping it by VPN